# C# async: How does a thread remember its local variables?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

In multithreading, threads share a several things, but not local variables. Each thread maintains its own copy of the stack where local variables are stored. Nice, but what happens in this case?

```csharp
public async Task<string> ReadFile()
{
    var fileName = GenerateFileName();

    using (var reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        var fileText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return fileName + "|" + fileText;
    }
}
```

When the IO operation starts, the thread goes to sleep (or doing other things), and when it (or other one) backs to continue executing the function, how does it remember the value of `fileName`? What goes on here with the stack?

Comment: Try deobfuscating your code, or shoving it into something like [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/). You'll see that the compiler will generate a private class, e.g. `private sealed class <ReadFile>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine` which keeps the state.

Comment: Or a struct if you build in release mode. The aync machinery is really complex for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: Also see, e.g. [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/11/30/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) or [Async and Await - How is order of execution maintained?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31705405/1364007) or [C# Async: What is it, and how does it work?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-tools/c-async-what-is-it-and-how-does-it-work/).

Comment: I created an MCVE on SharpLab [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgzABFATHAwgWAFAG9Nzw+KADgQBY4AlAUwENgAxASwBsqAKASl3xw334QAGOGwBuNAE5wJtYFSkBeBAEYAdAEkA8qqatVmgA5UAdgBUqADwAubYwFdmzDlz4C8vN2/FSAZiyrm1nBKUACc0rLyqtR0pgD2AKLGwACCAM4AnsYAxpwA3NxuAL6FcCUYRUA==) for you.

Comment: Your question is actually about how a _Task_ stores local data. Formal answer: It's an implementation detail, not your concern. But the previous comments point you to explanations.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Wow, thanks a lot!

Comment: @HenkHolterman it can make things a bit unexpected with garbage collection, as the locals aren't really local.

Comment: @JonHanna What would be the unexpected bit?  And it's the same for any closed-over var.

Comment: @HenkHolterman they'll keep things rooted for longer, but yes, it's the same as for any closed-over variable.

Comment: The state machin is not a root, I still don't see _any_ difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens in a similar way to how `yield` methods store their locals: It creates a `struct` that has the variables that are local in the C# as fields.

So your code produces something that if `aysnc` didn't exist would have to be coded like:

```
private struct ReadFileAsyncStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int _state;
    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<string> _builder;
    private string _fileName;
    private string _fileText;
    private StreamReader _reader;
    TaskAwaiter<string> _awaiter;
    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_state != 0)
            {
                goto afterSetup;
            }

            _fileName = GenerateFileName();
            _reader = File.OpenText(_fileName);
            TaskAwaiter<string> awaiter = _reader.ReadToEndAsync().GetAwaiter();
            _state = -1;
            if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
            {
                _awaiter = awaiter;
                _builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TaskAwaiter<string>, ReadFileAsyncStateMachine>(ref awaiter, ref this);
                return;
            }

        afterSetup:
            awaiter = _awaiter;
            _fileText = awaiter.GetResult();
            _state = -2;
            _builder.SetResult(_fileName + "|" + _fileText);
            _reader.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _state = -2;
            _builder.SetException(exception);
            _reader?.Dispose();
            return;
        }
    }
    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine param0)
    {
        _builder.SetStateMachine(param0);
    }
}

public Task<string> ReadFile()
{
    ReadFileAsyncStateMachine stateMachine = new ReadFileAsyncStateMachine();
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<string> builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<string>.Create();

    stateMachine._builder = builder;
    stateMachine._state = -1;
    builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return builder.Task;
}
```

The `ReadFileAsyncStateMachine` handles both the possibility of `ReadToEndAsync()` completing immediately, in which case the `Task<string>` returned is completed immediately and has a result, or running, in which case the `Task<string>` returned is itself running and a subsequent call will happen to `MoveNext()` which will complete it. Exceptions are also handled.

As you can see, the locals in the C# are fields in the implementation.

Comment: (Just to add for completeness: `yield` methods use a class to store their local state on. There's no point in using a struct here, as it would get boxed to an `IEnumerable<T>` anyway)

Comment: @canton7 true, and also debug builds use `class` with `async` because the CLR will only allow changing the fields of a class in the way that edit-and-continue would require.