# What mechanism does an async button click handler maintain separate local variables for each invocation?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task

This code does what you would expect: Two clicks of the button in rapid succession will start two tasks and print two messages with two different local variable values.

```
private bool _dummy;
        
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int a;
  if (_dummy == false)
  { 
    a = 1; 
    _dummy = true; 
  }
  else
  { 
    a = 99;
    _dummy = false;
  }

  Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss:fff} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} {a} click pre delay");
  Task dtask = Task.Delay(2000);
  await dtask;
  Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss:fff} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} {a} {dtask.Id} click post delay");
}
```

Resulting messages:

```
15:21:52:111 1 1 click pre delay
15:21:52:595 1 99 click pre delay
15:21:54:120 1 1 7 click post delay
15:21:54:615 1 99 9 click post delay
```

The question is: what mechanism allows this to work? How does the **first post-await resumption** of the method maintain a separate stack for the local value and **stay disentangled** from the **second post-await resumption**?

I know (or at least have a vague concept) that threads have independent stacks, but in this situation everything is on the single GUI thread (verified by printing `ManagedThreadId`.)

This question is similar to [C# async: How does a thread remember its local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941894/c-sharp-async-how-does-a-thread-remember-its-local-variables), but I don't know if I would consider them true duplicates. My question is specifically about disentangling *temporally* overlapping invocations.

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping invocations"? The first one happens, it has its own set of values created specially for that instance. The second one happens, it has its own set of values, also created specially for *that* instance. Another one happens, it also has its own specially created set of values.

Comment: By "overlapping invocations" I mean, in the passage of time, that both predelay message outputs temporally pre-date both postdelay message outputs. The two tasks are (for a time) parallel.

Comment: @amonroejj What exactly is overlapping? You can have multiple tasks and multiple threads, but a thread can work on only one thing. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

Comment: Read up on how `async` and `await` works.  When you await something (a task), a _continuation_ gets created that captures the state of world at the point where the task starts.  When the task completes, the continuation gets fired up and continues the work.  That's where the state is maintained - in that tiny state machine

Answer (score 4):

Internally an `async` invocation works by creating a state machine.  The various state machines (one per invocation) run independently and have their respectively independent variables.

Have a look at what your example is lowered to for instance on "[here](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)".

The `AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted` method connects the Task with the StateMachine making sure the `MoveNext` method is called when the Task is completed. See "[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asynctaskmethodbuilder.awaitunsafeoncompleted)".

Comment: From the decompilation I can see how the inner class is instantiated and started (which explains how the first half of the state machine runs), but it's not shown in the decompilation (or I am too stupid to see it) how .MoveNext() gets called a second time to run the latter half of the state machine.

Comment: The `AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted` method connects the Task with the StateMachine making sure the MoveNext method is called when the Task is completed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.asynctaskmethodbuilder.awaitunsafeoncompleted

Comment: @NineBerry expand your answer with details regarding `AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted` and I will accept it as selected answer.

Answer (score 4):

The c# compiler creates for each `async` method an internal class that implements a state machine. The local variables in the method are turned into fields of the class.

For each invocation of the method a new instance of that internal class is created. That is how overlapping executions of the method use different sets of local variables: The local variables are represented by fields of different instances of the internally generated StateMachine class.

You can see an example of the compiler-generated code at https://sharplab.io/#gist:b0bda78721855033b6423b6cd872d05e

Answer (score 1):

> I know (or at least have a vague concept) that threads have independent stacks, but in this situation everything is on the single GUI thread (verified by printing `ManagedThreadId`.)

This is true, but the `button1_Click` event handler is actually an **asynchronous execution flow** that transcends threads. If the execution flow was synchronous, for example by replacing the `await Task.Delay(2000)` with `Thread.Sleep(2000)`, you wouldn't even be able to click the button twice because the UI would freeze after the first click.

Under the hood the `Task.Delay` task completes on a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread. At that moment the continuation after the `await` is rescheduled to the UI thread via a transparent but complex mechanism, that involves the [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext) class and the [`Control.BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) method ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/v8.0.0/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs#L90)). You can prevent this redirection by configuring the `await` with the [`ConfigureAwait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait) method:

```
await dtask.ConfigureAwait(false); // Don't marshal the continuation back
                                   // to the captured synchronization context.
```

This way the continuation after the `await` will run directly on the thread that completed the `Task.Delay` task, which will be a `ThreadPool` thread, because of how the `Task.Delay` method is implemented internally. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543240/what-thread-runs-the-code-after-the-await-keyword/77392646#77392646) for more details.